Set the position of several vertexes to the position of the very first one
I want to save the position of vertex (drawn in red) and vertex (painted in green), apply the position by Z, is it possible to implement this somehow?
I have Vertex Groups.
I make Blur of this group and I want to make the next vertexes from it (green color) to have Z position exactly the same as red vertexes.
But it should work logically as it is drawn in yellow color - the position of red vertex is taken and the next vertexes should be assigned the Z position from red vertex.
I need this for a very big and huge object and I have a lot of generation going on and this logic will save me a lot.





Sorry, it's hard to understand what you want to do. Can you add a brief description? What do you mean by "I want to save the position of vertex (drawn in red) and vertex (painted in green),  apply the position by Z"?

I supplemented the post with screenshots and described my question in more detail.

the tricky part about this is to group those vertices. An "edge loops" node is awaiting to be merged into main branch, meanwhile you could analyze your mesh using a repeat zone... Perhaps in your particular case you can separate edges into streets and avenues (dominant x vs dominant y),then you can convert to curves, capture spline indices, convert back to mesh, and sample which avenue and street a vertex belongs to etc.

Can you please help me with an example? I don't really understand your point.

Is the mesh always a square grid with the red vertices at the edge? You can get the "path" (edges) starting at the red vertices along the 3 yellow vertices with the help of the Shortest Edge Paths node for each red vertex. With a Sample Nearest and Sample Index node you should be able to get the vertices of the mesh. Last but not least, you need to set the Z-value of the red vertices (root) to the corresponding yellow vertices. I haven't figured out the last part but I can show you the first part.

Thanks, I already found a solution that works 90% of the time and in my case it works 100% of the time.

I will not describe, I'll just post a screenshot, if anyone will help later.

Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips and image only posts rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps name a few key nodes used and their names, so they can be indexed and searched for by future users
